# Activity not destroyed

Tags: android

I have an app which goes to background when the user press the back button-

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(setIntent);
 }
```

So the only way the user will shutdown the app is by using the `task manager` and manually stop it.

Now, I'm trying to test my `onDestroy` by closing my app using the `task manager` in my Android device,
yet, on `Android Studio` the app seem to be still alive, it says `Session: '<app_name>' : running` and `onDestroy` is not called.

Why is that and how can I fix it?

**I want to see that `onDestroy` is called when I'm stopping my app using the `task manager` and by manually stopping it, as the user will have to do if he wants to shut my app down, Not by pressing back button. by pressing back button the app will be alive and its fine, it's what I want.

Comment: I don't believe `onDestroy` or any other function will be called when you stop the app via task manager. I believe it literally kills the process and doesn't give your app a chance to do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under **Settings** → **Developer Options**, go to the Apps section and enable "**Don't keep activities**" option.
Then every time you hit the back button the App will be destroyed.
I you want to override the Back Button action to destroy app you could override onKeyDown in your Activity

```
  @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
    {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: On the Developer Settings of your device http://media02.hongkiat.com/android-developer-options-hidden-features/dont-keep-activities.jpg

Comment: Ok, saw it, it works, but I need to test the app the same way it will run in a normal way, I mean, by presing the back button, It should go to background and not to be destroyed, and when the user is stopping the app, the `onDestroy` should be called. What you suggested is to destroy the app when the user press the back button.

Comment: In this case you can override @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
    {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

Answer (score 3):

Why relaunch the activity on back pressed? Just do nothing.

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
 }
```

Comment: onDestroy() is an unreliable hook, as per Google's documentation. It won't be triggered on automated cleanup of the app, and it may not do it in manual either.

Answer (score 0):

Call **`finish()`** to destroy an Activity.

```
@Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(setIntent);
    finish();
 }
```

Comment: when should I call it? I need it to be performed when to user is stopping the app

Comment: thanks, but I need it to work when the user is stopping the app manually, I'll edit my question

Comment: But, doesn't your question say that you want to destroy it? I think I am getting confused here.

Answer (score 0):

You can either call `finish();` , for ex, after `startActivity(setIntent);`

Or, you can call `super.onBackPressed();`, also at the end.

Comment: sorry but it's not what I asked